# Xcode can't change back to landscape from portrait automatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an iPhone app in which the `RootViewController` instance starts out in the landscape mode. It supports camera so it changes to portrait mode to take a photo. Once done it comes back to the `RootViewController` instance but the orientation doesn't change to landscape. I want this to automatically shift to the landscape orientation.

I tried adding

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO]
```

in `viewWillAppear` method of `RootViewController` or `viewWillDisapper` of `CameraViewController` but orientation doesn't change. How do I programmatically change the orientation?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing following method in your controller.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Hope it helps.